# URL is replaced but component doesn't refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I want handle error 401 and redirect user to login route. My method look like this.
I make **history.js**

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const history = new createBrowserHistory();
```

And I use that in 2 places - like props of Router and operation (in this file i fetch user details and I add that into redux store)

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/login">
            <Login />
        </Route>
            <Route path="/login">
                <Login />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/first">
                <First />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
                <Redirect to="/first" />
            </Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

**operation.js**

```
const fetchUser = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axiosConfig.get('api/get-user');
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response.status == 401) {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    }
}

export const getUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const user = await fetchUser();
        dispatch(actions.setUser(user));
    } catch {
        dispatch(history.replace('main/#/login'));
    }
}
```

If a user isn't logged, URL is replaced but... component does not refresh. For example - I try to run First which need to logged. URL was changed to login but I saw First component. Only if I refresh website I see login route. Where is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to use the `push` method instead of the `replace` method?

```
history.push('main/#/login');
```

In this case I don't think you need to wrap it in `dispatch`. I'm not sure what you're dispatching when you're routing. I've never seen this before.